# Do I have a bad video card?

Tags: windows, windows-xp, laptop, video, display

I think this is the right spot to post this question.  Please don't flame me if it isn't.  My work computer is a Dell Prescision M6400 laptop.  I use the VGA output to a second monitor.  There is something wrong with my second monitor's output.  Here is a screenshot of my desktop.

[image: screenshot of corrupted desktop]

You can see fragments of the right side of a Windows File Explorer window in the image.  Is this a bad video card?

Comment: Can you see the desktop image?  It doesn't show on my question posting.

Comment: Not showing for me - though when I view it directly I can see it. However, it is very large - try reducing the size and re-uploading it.

Comment: No cannot see the destop image

Comment: here's a smaller image - http://www.freeimagehosting.net/image.php?cf62eaa0e4.jpg

Answer (score 1):

Aha the joys of XP! No, I would not think that it is a video card issue - it seems to me that you were dragging the Explorer window from one screen to the other and it lagged.

Comment: To add to this: Remember that Windows XP always paints directly to the screen. windows covered by other windows are not redrawn at all and when you move windows around they are instructed to redraw themselves. If one program decides to become unresponsive, then you get what you see here since it won't redraw (or won't do it properly). In this case it appears to be Explorer who got a little stuck. This is just a little software problem, neither related to your hardware or drivers.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like a problem with the driver, not bad hardware.